# Indesign Script for PDF Object Layer Options

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I have an indesign document with multiple pages. each page has a linked pdf in it. each pdf has 3 layers within it and  in order to turn these layers on or off, you have to right click, select Object Layer Options, and then manually turn on or off layers.

I would like to loop through all my pages and turn on a layer in the PDF using a script. i have been messing with graphicLayerOptions.graphicLayers but keep running into an error when telling it to turn the currentVisibilty=true;

```
var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
var docLength = myDocument.pages.length; 
var myPages = myDocument.pages

for (var i = 0; i < docLength; i++) {
    var labelPlaceholder = myDocument.allGraphics;
    var labelArtwork = labelPlaceholder[0];
    var artworkLayers = labelArtwork.graphicLayerOptions.graphicLayers;
    artworkLayers.item("Die Copy").currentVisibility = true;

}
```

Comment: Small update: 'var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
var docLength = myDocument.pages.length; 
var myPages = myDocument.pages

for (var i = 0; i < docLength; i++) {
    var labelPlaceholder = myDocument.allGraphics;
    var labelArtwork = labelPlaceholder[0];
    var artworkLayers = labelArtwork.graphicLayerOptions.graphicLayers;
    // artworkLayers.item("Die Copy").currentVisibility = true;
    // alert(artworkLayers.length)
    artworkLayers[0].currentVisibility = true;

}' this works at communicating with the pdf layers, but now i need to figure out how to loop through each page

Answer (score 1):

i got it working...l

```
var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
var docLength = myDocument.pages.length; 
var myPages = myDocument.pages

for (var i = 0; i < docLength; i++) {
    var labelPlaceholder = myPages[i].allGraphics;
    var labelArtwork = labelPlaceholder[0];
    var artworkLayers = labelArtwork.graphicLayerOptions.graphicLayers;
    artworkLayers[0].currentVisibility = true;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case. In InDesing (Illustrator, etc) you have two options to get an item from a collection.

By its number:

```
var layer = app.activeDocument.layers[0];
```

By its name:

```
var layer = app.activeDocument.layers.itemByName("Die Copy");
```

Later options is less reliable. Not all collections has this method. I don't know if it (PDF layers) is the case, though.